# Site removing www from URL/address in magento Hosted on Plesk server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, plesk

I posted this question on magento.stackexchange but not get my solution so posting here.Can view on this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12217/site-removing-www-from-address-in-magento). I want that user can access my site with or without www.But it didn't work with www.
My site removing www from address and redirect to non www address like http://example.co.uk.I write this code in htaccess for www but didn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^babycave.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.babycave.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can any body guide me where the issue is ? from admin side i setted secure and unsecure url's like `http://babycave.co.uk/`.Thanks

Below is my htaccess file:

```
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^babycave.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.babycave.co.uk$1 [R=301]

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: Plesk is NOT a server; it is a web-based software to manage the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your configuration in `PLesk` (assuming you have Plesk 11.x)

In Plesk admin -> your domain -> "Hosting Settings" check the Preffered Domain option.

The default option in my setup is "`domain.tld`". 
You can change it to "`www.domain.tld`" and check to see if your problem is fixed.

Comment: yes you are right it is  "domain.tld".But if i change it to www.domain.tld it generate error of redirect loop.?

Comment: Solved need to change secure and unsecure urls from db then it will works thanks alot.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi its admin side of `magento ` secure and unsecure url structure.So when we set the address their it will working as i want.

Comment: So what was the old configuration, what new config you set for secure and unsecure? Please be specific

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible problems here.

**SERVER SETTINGS**:

Your web server needs to be configured to except the www. alias.

I am not sure how you do this via plesk but I would suggest checking your apache and dns settings to make sure they are both configured to handle both example.com and www.example.com

in Apache you can do this in your vhost section with the following statements

```
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
```

**MAGENTO SETTINGS**:

You do not need to modify your htaccess from the default provided by magento as it will accept both www.example.com and example.com.

Magento will however rewrite the URL to what ever is set in the following database table.

core_config_data 
under path

web/unsecure/base_url 
and 
web/secure/base_url

So both addresses will be able to get to your store but one needs to be the default and magento will always rewrite the url to be that one.

Comment: thanks voted you but accept andreasr answer as he replied first.

Answer (score -1):

This will redirect `babycave.co.uk`to `www.babycave.co.uk`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.babycave.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.babycave.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```